# NextGen album doesn't open gallery

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I've installed NextGEN Basic plugin. I've created a gallery and an album. If I insert album on a page and I click on it, it opens my last blog post instead of a gallery. Any clue what I've done wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a support question you should raise on the plugin's home page.

Comment: As basic user I don't think I'll get any support but you're right I'll try. Thx